# Why I can't found git log of merge commit in my repository

Tags: git, logging, merge, commit

I will give you directly an example of the problem.

I try to make git log of commit that we could find in the git online,
but in local it give an error of unknown revision or path.

Example:
commit: 06cf1bf

this is the link online: 
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/06cf1bf254dc1edf9faa398be099332e00f4778e

but when I make the

> git log $commit

I can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at a commit on GitHub (for instance [`dropwizard/dropwizard` commit 117cd08](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/117cd08130cfebb1e78345672edf7b922d6e215e)), you see the branch it is part of.

The commit you reference ([06cf1bf2](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/06cf1bf254dc1edf9faa398be099332e00f4778e)) has no branch referencing it.
While it is directly accessible on GitHub, it might not be part of a regular `git clone`.
May be a recent `git push --force` has rewritten part of the history of that repo, making the commit part of the reflog of the remote repo.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that I resolved the problem. It Might be a virtual commit that is not part of the original repository. Thank you for your responses. 
This is a link for more explanation from github:

```
https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone/
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I alluded to in my answer: a commit created, but not referenced by any branch or tag.

Comment: Note that it HAS to be referenced by something to remain over time, otherwise it eventually be purged by the garbage collector…

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have fetched this remote content first ? Try

```
git fetch
```

or

```
git remote update
```

… to synchronize your local repository with the remote one and try again.

You should also check what's in `$commit`. Be aware that these commands won't automatically merge this content to your local branches neither (`git pull` will) but once the object is repatriated into your local object collection, you're able to invoke it by its SHA1 sum.

Comment: no I waited for a command that show me the log of a merge commit. The repository is updated and there is no need to make the fetch